# como se debe configurar htaccess para poder incrustar .php en archivos HTML

Tags: php, html, html5, .htaccess

Tengo una web en html, css y javascript (sin librerias ni framework) y necesito incrustar footer y header externo para que sea mas simple su mantenimiento. Encontré el siguiente código que lo resolvería, pero aclaran que, de no funcionar, se debe configurar el .htaccess y no tengo idea a que se refiere...

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Titulo de pagina</title>
</head>

<body>
  <?php
include "header.html";
?>
    // Todo el contenido de la pagina... etc...
    <?php
include "footer.html";
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No debes hacer nada en el .htaccess, solo si tu apache2 y PHP estan instalado no vas a tener problema con ese codigo

Comment: perfecto! espero que esten instalados. muchas gracias

Comment: lo único que debes cambiar para que funcione, es la extensión del archivo; es decir en lugar de ser archivo.html cambialo por archivo.php y de este modo dentro de un servidor apache funcionará como esperas

Comment: ahora si lo que quieres es no modificar tu extension .html en el .htaccess agregas algo como `AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si tu pregunta va mas a

> Como agregar codigo PHP a paginas con extensiones `.html` o `.htm`

Debes hacer lo siguiente :

En la raiz del proyecto creas el archivo si no existe`.htaccess` y debes agregar la siguiente linea:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Significa que la extensiones `.html`o `.htm` son aplicaciones de PHP

Dejo la documentacion sobre [AddType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)

Comment: esa es exactamente la respuesta sobre el archivo .htaccess que estaba necesitando. Una ultima consulta: conviene mas trabajar los archivos con extension .php o .html? Recien estoy iniciando y hasta el momento no habia utilizado xampp ni extensiones .php pero veo que es mas o menos lo mismo...

Comment: lo ideal es que sea con extension .php, se te hace mas facil identificar cual tiene codigo PHP y cual no, ademas no tienes que hacer malabares(como este) para que te funcione bien tu servidor web

Comment: perfecto! muchas gracias voy a tomar tu consejo ;)

Answer (score 2):

Para que tu código funcione debes considerar lo siguiente:

la extensión del archivo

Los archivos que deseas ejecuten lógica de lenguaje como **PHP**; entonces deben tener extensión `.php`; a lo que me refiero es:

en lugar de tener esto: `archivo.html`

debes tener esto: `archivo.php`

Lo siguiente es que debes ejecutar estos archivos desde un servidor apache o ngnix; si estas empezando y trabajas en Windows; el primero lo tienes en paquetes como XAMPP que te engloban ya: PHP, MySQL, Apache

Bajo el escenario supuesto anterior, debes guardar tu proyecto en la siguiente ruta

```
xampp/htdocs
```

Y dentro de HTDOCS vas a pegar tu carpeta con tu proyecto; una vez hecho lo anterior vas a buscar abrir el panel de xampp desde Inicio en Windows y escribiendo xampp panel

Le vas a dar ejecutar a Apache y posterior en tu navegador harás lo siguiente

```
localhost/nombreCarpetaProyecto
```

Donde nombreCarpetaProyecto es el nombre de la carpeta donde almacenaste tu proyecto

Nota

Debes considerar que Apache por defecto va a buscar un archivo con el nombre `index.php` para cargar su contenido en el navegador, de lo contrario te mostrará la lista de archivos que tienes almacenados, considera nombrar uno así como te digo

Al menos para lo que mencionas no necesitas configurar nada en el `.htaccess`

Comment: gracias por la observación @JackNavaRow

Comment: un gracias gigante por la explicación detallada! ya que no lograba que funcionara solo con esas lineas de código.